# very frustrated with the mysql count function

Tags: mysql

I have racked my brain for two days on this. I need to count the members are in each age group, but cannot figure out how. I have made it this far, but this only shows the age groups of members but does not count them.

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(birth_date) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE(), 5) < RIGHT (birth_date, 5)) BETWEEN 12 AND 18 THEN '12-18'
    WHEN YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(birth_date) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE(), 5) < RIGHT (birth_date, 5)) BETWEEN 19 AND 55 then '19-55'
ELSE '56 or older'
END AS age_group
FROM members
ORDER BY age_group
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the query to perform a count. You also need to group by the field you want counted.

Try this:

```
select count(*) as the_count, 
  case
    when YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(birth_date) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE(), 5) < RIGHT (birth_date, 5)) between 12 AND 18 THEN '12-18' 
    when YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(birth_date) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE(), 5) < RIGHT (birth_date, 5)) between 19 AND 55 then '19-55' 
    else '56 or older'
  end
  as age_group
from members group by age_group order by age_group;
```

Click the link below for a running demo:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2271b/3)

Answer (score 1):

You have already extracted the data you need. To count it, embed it as a sub query and count the results for each group via a group by clause. By adding the unique identifier for each member in the sub query, it allows the counts of the members in each group to survive the group by (ie. Not get collapsed into a single row per group).

```
SELECT age_group, COUNT(*) AS group_count
FROM
    (SELECT
        - -  add a unique identifier for each member here as a select attribute, 
        CASE 
            WHEN YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) -  YEAR(birth_date) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE(), 5) < RIGHT (birth_date, 5)) BETWEEN 12 AND 18 THEN '12-18' 
            WHEN YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(birth_date) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE(), 5) < RIGHT (birth_date, 5)) BETWEEN 19 AND 55 then '19-55' ELSE '56 or older' END AS age_group 
    FROM members) AS tab_age_groups
GROUP BY age_group
ORDER BY age_group;
```

Comment: Yours is a very nice answer. Sorry I am on mobile. Didn't update me!

Comment: No worries, glad to see your efforts on SO :-)